# Heroku buildpack horse ignoring node version in package.json

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, meteor, npm

I am a fairly newbie Meteor developer trying to get an app to deploy to a Heroku server.

The main issue is that bcrypt needs a newer version of node in order to work and for some reason, the node version specified in 'engines' in package.json does not work with AdmitHub's buildpack horse for meteor - it keeps using a much older version that isn't recommended (node v0.10.48 and npm v2.15.1) for both the bcrypt version I am running (3.0.6) and Meteor (1.8.1). I am trying to use Node v10.16.2 and npm v6.10.3

I have tried ensuring that the project name is matched by the repo name in the package.json, setting it to a few different versions.
I have also tested the use of the node buildpack and it gets the right versions when using that json but, it won't run due to it not being the meteor buildpack.

#Package.json#

```
 {
    "name": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "version": "5.4.0",
    "private": true,
    "engines":{"npm":"6.10.3", "node":"10.16.2"},
    "scripts": {
        "tsc": "tsc react-meteor-data.ts",
        "postinstall": "run-s build:*",
        "start": "run-s build watch:server",
        "test": "run-p lint ava",
        "test:server": "meteor test --once --driver-package 
    dispatch:mocha --port 3100 --settings settings.test.json",
        "test:server:watch": "TEST_WATCH=1 meteor test --driver- 
   package dispatch:mocha --port 3100 --settings settings.test.json",
        "ava": "NODE_ENV=test ava --verbose tests",
        "lint": "standard | snazzy",
        "lint:fix": "standard --fix",
        "build": "run-s build:*",
        "build:css": "postcss --config ./postcss.config.js --output ./client/bundle.css ./imports/ui/main.css",
        "watch": "run-p watch:*",
        "watch:css": "nodemon --quiet --watch ./imports/ui --ext css --exec npm run build:css",
        "watch:server": "meteor run --settings settings.json"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@types/react": "^16.9.2",
        "assert": "^2.0.0",
        "async": "^2.6.3",
        "autoprefixer": "^6.5.1",
        "babel-plugin-transform-class-properties": "^6.24.1",
        "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.16.0",
        "babel-preset-react": "^6.16.0",
        "babel-register": "^6.26.0",
        "babel-runtime": "6.18.0",
        "basscss": "^8.1.0",
        "basscss-background-colors": "^2.1.0",
        "basscss-colors": "^2.2.0",
        "basscss-responsive-margin": "^1.1.0",
        "basscss-responsive-padding": "^1.1.0",
        "bcrypt": "^3.0.6",
        "child_process": "^1.0.2",
        "classnames": "^2.2.6",
        "create-react-class": "^15.6.3",
        "crypto": "^1.0.1",
        "debug": "^2.6.9",
        "deep-equal": "^1.0.1",
        "escape-string-regexp": "^1.0.5",
        "event-loop-lag": "^1.4.0",
        "fibers": "^4.0.1",
        "fs": "0.0.1-security",
        "he": "^1.2.0",
        "iso-3166-1-alpha-2": "^1.0.0",
        "joi-browser": "^10.6.1",
        "jquery": "^3.4.1",
        "lodash": "^4.17.15",
        "meteor-babel": "^7.5.7",
        "meteor-babel-helpers": "0.0.3",
        "meteor-node-stubs": "~0.2.0",
        "meteor-promise": "^0.8.7",
        "meteor-user-roles": "^1.1.7",
        "moment": "^2.24.0",
        "mongodb": "^3.3.0",
        "node-diff": "^0.2.0",
        "node4mailer": "^4.0.3",
        "npm-run-all": "^3.1.1",
        "os": "^0.1.1",
        "path": "^0.12.7",
        "postcss": "^5.2.18",
        "postcss-calc": "^5.3.1",
        "postcss-cli": "^2.6.0",
        "postcss-custom-media": "^5.0.1",
        "postcss-custom-properties": "^5.0.1",
        "postcss-easy-import": "^1.0.1",
        "postcss-functions": "^2.1.1",
        "postcss-import": "^8.1.2",
        "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
        "query-string": "^6.8.2",
        "react": "^16.9.0",
        "react-addons-pure-render-mixin": "^15.6.2",
        "react-day-picker": "^7.3.2",
        "react-dom": "^16.9.0",
        "react-helmet": "^5.2.1",
        "react-router-dom": "^5.0.1",
        "semver": "^6.3.0",
        "smartsurvey-client": "^1.2.0",
        "source-map-support": "^0.5.13",
        "underscore": "^1.9.1",
        "url": "^0.11.0"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "ava": "^0.19.1",
        "babel-eslint": "^7.2.2",
        "enzyme": "^3.10.0",
        "faker": "^4.1.0",
        "nodemon": "^1.19.1",
        "pre-commit": "^1.1.3",
        "snazzy": "^7.1.1",
        "standard": "^10.0.3"
    },
    "ava": {
        "babel": "inherit",
        "require": [
            "babel-register"
        ]
    },
    "standard": {
        "parser": "babel-eslint"
    }
}
```

#Console Log#

```
 git push heroku master
Enumerating objects: 200, done.
Counting objects: 100% (200/200), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (107/107), done.
Writing objects: 100% (111/111), 115.45 KiB | 2.31 MiB/s, done.
Total 111 (delta 49), reused 0 (delta 0)
remote: Compressing source files... done.
remote: Building source:
remote:
remote: -----> Node.js app detected
remote: -----> Installing node
remote: -----> Installing meteor
remote: Downloading Meteor distribution
remote:
remote: Meteor 1.8.1 has been installed in your home directory (~/.meteor).
remote:
remote: Now you need to do one of the following:
remote:
remote:   (1) Add "$HOME/.meteor" to your path, or
remote:   (2) Run this command as root:
remote:         cp "/app/tmp/buildpacks/70b014ca5f012fbcd571457366ff69b27da3ac5fa3f75060cd18fbc3bb7e4197c59b93620c093e230d716bdebaaf233e031e247f905457a1aeae6c4cdd57a918/meteor-Llwd/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/1.8.1/mt-os.linux.x86_64/scripts/admin/launch-meteor" /usr/bin/meteor
remote:
remote: Then to get started, take a look at 'meteor --help' or see the docs at
remote: docs.meteor.com.
remote: npm WARN deprecated crypto@1.0.1: This package is no longer supported. It's now a built-in Node module. If you've depended on crypto, you should switch to the one that's built-in.
remote: npm WARN deprecated babel-preset-es2015@6.24.1:   Thanks for using Babel: we recommend using babel-preset-env now: please read https://babeljs.io/env to update!
remote: npm WARN engine bcrypt@3.0.6: wanted: {"node":">= 6.0.0"} (current: {"node":"0.10.48","npm":"2.15.1"})
remote: npm WARN engine node4mailer@4.0.3: wanted: {"node":">=4.0.0"} (current: 
remote: npm WARN engine randexp@0.4.6: wanted: {"node":">=0.12"} (current: {"node":"0.10.48","npm":"2.15.1"})// does this warning for virtually all pacakages
remote:
remote: > bcrypt@3.0.6 install /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/bcrypt
remote: > node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
remote:
remote: node-pre-gyp WARN Using needle for node-pre-gyp https download
remote:
remote: /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/tar/lib/create.js:4
remote: const hlo = require('./high-level-opt.js')
remote: ^^^^^
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! UNCAUGHT EXCEPTION
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! stack SyntaxError: Use of const in strict mode.
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Module._compile (module.js:439:25)
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at require (module.js:380:17)
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Object.<anonymous> (/tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/node-pre-gyp/node_modules/tar/index.js:4:30)
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! stack     at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1048-aws
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! command "node" "/tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/bcrypt/node_modules/.bin/node-pre-gyp" "install" "--fallback-to-build"
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/bcrypt
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.48
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! node-pre-gyp -v v0.12.0
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! This is a bug in `node-pre-gyp`.
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR! Try to update node-pre-gyp and file an issue if it does not help:
remote: node-pre-gyp ERR!     <https://github.com/mapbox/node-pre-gyp/issues>
remote: npm WARN engine ret@0.1.15: wanted: {"node":">=0.12"} (current: {"node":"0.10.48","npm":"2.15.1"})
remote:
remote: > nodemon@1.19.2 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/nodemon
remote: > node bin/postinstall || exit 0
remote:
remote: Love nodemon? You can now support the project via the open collective:
remote:  > https://opencollective.com/nodemon/donate
remote:
remote: npm WARN engine request@2.88.0: wanted: {"node":">= 4"} (current: {"node":"0.10.48","npm":"2.15.1"})
remote:
remote: > fibers@4.0.1 install /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/fibers
remote: > node build.js || nodejs build.js
remote:
remote: make: Entering directory '/tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/fibers/build'
remote:   CXX(target) Release/obj.target/fibers/src/fibers.o
remote: ../src/fibers.cc: In function ‘v8::Handle<v8::Object> uni::NewInstance(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Function>, int, v8::Local<v8::Value>*)’:
remote: ../src/fibers.cc:120:38: error: ‘class v8::Local<v8::Object>’ has no member named ‘ToLocalChecked’
remote:    return fn->NewInstance(argc, argv).ToLocalChecked();
remote:                                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote: ../src/fibers.cc: In function ‘void uni::SetAccessor(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::String>, uni::FunctionType (*)(v8::Local<v8::String>, const GetterCallbackInfo&), void (*)(v8::Local<v8::String>, v8::Local<v8::Value>, const SetterCallbackInfo&))’:
remote: ../src/fibers.cc:378:30: error: ‘AccessorNameGetterCallback’ was not declared in this scope
remote:    object->SetAccessor(name, (AccessorNameGetterCallback)getter, (AccessorNameSetterCallback)setter);
remote:                               ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote: ../src/fibers.cc:378:66: error: ‘AccessorNameSetterCallback’ was not declared in this scope
remote:    object->SetAccessor(name, (AccessorNameGetterCallback)getter, (AccessorNameSetterCallback)setter);
remote:                                                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote: ../src/fibers.cc: In static member function ‘static uni::FunctionType Fiber::New(const Arguments&)’:
remote: ../src/fibers.cc:546:91: error: could not convert ‘uni::Deref<v8::FunctionTemplate>(v8::Isolate::GetCurrent(), Fiber::tmpl)’ from ‘v8::Handle<v8::FunctionTemplate>’ to ‘v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate>’
remote:      return uni::Return(uni::NewInstance(Isolate::GetCurrent(), uni::GetFunction(uni::Deref(Isolate::GetCurrent(), tmpl)), 1, argv), args);
remote:                                                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote: ../src/fibers.cc:550:76: error: no matching function for call to ‘Fiber::Fiber(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>&, v8::Handle<v8::Context>)’
remote:     new Fiber(args.This(), fn, uni::GetCurrentContext(Isolate::GetCurrent()));
remote:                                                                             ^
remote: ../src/fibers.cc:435:3: note: candidate: Fiber::Fiber(v8::Local<v8::Object>, v8::Local<v8::Function>, v8::Local<v8::Context>)
remote:    Fiber(Local<Object> handle, Local<Function> cb, Local<Context> v8_context) :
remote:    ^~~~~
remote: ../src/fibers.cc:435:3: note:   no known conversion for argument 3 from ‘v8::Handle<v8::Context>’ to ‘v8::Local<v8::Context>’
remote: ../src/fibers.cc:405:7: note: candidate: constexpr Fiber::Fiber(const Fiber&)
remote:  class Fiber {
remote:        ^~~~~
remote: ../src/fibers.cc:405:7: note:   candidate expects 1 argument, 3 provided
remote: ../src/fibers.cc: In static member function ‘static uni::FunctionType Fiber::Reset(const Arguments&)’:
remote: ../src/fibers.cc:637:33: error: conversion from ‘v8::Handle<v8::Value>’ to non-scalar type ‘v8::Local<v8::Value>’ requested
remote:     Local<Value> val = uni::Deref(that.isolate, that.yielded);
remote:                        ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote: ../src/fibers.cc: In member function ‘v8::Local<v8::Value> Fiber::ReturnYielded()’:
remote: ../src/fibers.cc:705:33: error: conversion from ‘v8::Handle<v8::Value>’ to non-scalar type ‘v8::Local<v8::Value>’ requested
remote:     Local<Value> val = uni::Deref(isolate, yielded);
remote:                        ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote: ../src/fibers.cc:708:31: error: could not convert ‘uni::ThrowException(((Fiber*)this)->Fiber::isolate, val.v8::Local<v8::Value>::<anonymous>)’ from ‘v8::Handle<v8::Value>’ to ‘v8::Local<v8::Value>’
remote:      return uni::ThrowException(isolate, val);
remote:             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote: ../src/fibers.cc: In static member function ‘static void Fiber::RunFiber(void**)’:
remote: ../src/fibers.cc:736:43: error: conversion from ‘v8::Handle<v8::Context>’ to non-scalar type ‘v8::Local<v8::Context>’ requested
remote:      Local<Context> v8_context = uni::Deref(that.isolate, that.v8_context);
remote:                                  ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote: ../src/fibers.cc:744:36: error: could not convert ‘uni::Deref<v8::Function>(that.Fiber::isolate, that.Fiber::cb)’ from ‘v8::Handle<v8::Function>’ to ‘v8::Local<v8::Function>’
remote:       yielded = uni::Call(uni::Deref(that.isolate, that.cb), v8_context->Global(), 1, argv);
remote:                           ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote: ../src/fibers.cc:746:36: error: could not convert ‘uni::Deref<v8::Function>(that.Fiber::isolate, that.Fiber::cb)’ from ‘v8::Handle<v8::Function>’ to ‘v8::Local<v8::Function>’
remote:       yielded = uni::Call(uni::Deref(that.isolate, that.cb), v8_context->Global(), 0, NULL);
remote:                           ~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote: ../src/fibers.cc: In static member function ‘static void Fiber::Init(v8::Local<v8::Object>)’:
remote: ../src/fibers.cc:877:59: error: conversion from ‘v8::Handle<v8::FunctionTemplate>’ to non-scalar type ‘v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate>’ requested
remote:     Local<FunctionTemplate> tmpl = uni::NewFunctionTemplate(isolate, New);
remote:                                    ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote: ../src/fibers.cc:883:44: error: conversion from ‘v8::Handle<v8::Signature>’ to non-scalar type ‘v8::Local<v8::Signature>’ requested
remote:     Local<Signature> sig = uni::NewSignature(isolate, tmpl);
remote:                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote: ../src/fibers.cc:897:69: error: could not convert ‘uni::NewFunctionTemplate(isolate, Fiber::Yield_, v8::Handle<v8::Value>(), v8::Handle<v8::Signature>(), 0)’ from ‘v8::Handle<v8::FunctionTemplate>’ to ‘v8::Local<v8::FunctionTemplate>’
remote:     Local<Function> yield = uni::GetFunction(uni::NewFunctionTemplate(isolate, Yield_));
remote:                                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote: ../src/fibers.cc:898:50: error: conversion from ‘v8::Handle<v8::String>’ to non-scalar type ‘v8::Local<v8::String>’ requested
remote:     Local<String> sym_yield = uni::NewLatin1Symbol(isolate, "yield");
remote:                               ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote: ../src/fibers.cc:904:54: error: could not convert ‘uni::NewLatin1Symbol(isolate, ((const char*)"current"))’ from ‘v8::Handle<v8::String>’ to ‘v8::Local<v8::String>’
remote:     uni::SetAccessor(isolate, fn, uni::NewLatin1Symbol(isolate, "current"), GetCurrent);
remote:                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote: ../src/fibers.cc:905:54: error: could not convert ‘uni::NewLatin1Symbol(isolate, ((const char*)"poolSize"))’ from ‘v8::Handle<v8::String>’ to ‘v8::Local<v8::String>’
remote:     uni::SetAccessor(isolate, fn, uni::NewLatin1Symbol(isolate, "poolSize"), GetPoolSize, SetPoolSize);
remote:                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote: ../src/fibers.cc:906:54: error: could not convert ‘uni::NewLatin1Symbol(isolate, ((const char*)"fibersCreated"))’ from ‘v8::Handle<v8::String>’ to ‘v8::Local<v8::String>’
remote:     uni::SetAccessor(isolate, fn, uni::NewLatin1Symbol(isolate, "fibersCreated"), GetFibersCreated);
remote:                                   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
remote: fibers.target.mk:99: recipe for target 'Release/obj.target/fibers/src/fibers.o' failed
remote: make: *** [Release/obj.target/fibers/src/fibers.o] Error 1
remote: make: Leaving directory '/tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/fibers/build'
remote: gyp ERR! build error
remote: gyp ERR! stack Error: `make` failed with exit code: 2
remote: gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (/tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/.meteor/heroku_build/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/lib/build.js:276:23)
remote: gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
remote: gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:820:12)
remote: gyp ERR! System Linux 4.4.0-1048-aws
remote: gyp ERR! command "node" "/tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/.meteor/heroku_build/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" "rebuild" "--release"
remote: gyp ERR! cwd /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/fibers
remote: gyp ERR! node -v v0.10.48
remote: gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.3.1
remote: gyp ERR! not ok
remote: node-gyp exited with code: 1
remote: Please make sure you are using a supported platform and node version. If you
remote: would like to compile fibers on this machine please make sure you have setup your
remote: build environment--
remote: Windows + OS X instructions here: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp
remote: Ubuntu users please run: `sudo apt-get install g++ build-essential`
remote: RHEL users please run: `yum install gcc-c++` and `yum groupinstall 'Development Tools'`
remote: Alpine users please run: `sudo apk add python make g++`
remote: sh: 1: nodejs: not found
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/babel-register/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-amd/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoping/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-block-scoped-functions/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-typeof-symbol/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-umd/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-computed-properties/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-function-name/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-template-literals/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-arrow-functions/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/babel-preset-react/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-source/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/babel-preset-react/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-react-jsx-self/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-shorthand-properties/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore":
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-class-properties/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-literals/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-duplicate-keys/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-spread/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-for-of/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/babel-preset-react/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-react-display-name/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/node_modules/babel-plugin-check-es2015-constants/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
7e95dc/node_modules/ava/node_modules/@ava/babel-preset-transform-test-files/node_modules/babel-plugin-espower/node_modules/core-js
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/ava/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/babel-preset-es2015/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-regenerator/node_modules/regenerator-transform/node_modules/babel-types/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/ava/node_modules/@ava/babel-preset-stage-4/node_modules/babel-plugin-check-es2015-constants/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/ava/node_modules/@ava/babel-preset-stage-4/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-spread/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/ava/node_modules/@ava/babel-preset-stage-4/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-destructuring/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/ava/node_modules/@ava/babel-preset-stage-4/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-sticky-regex/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/ava/node_modules/@ava/babel-preset-stage-4/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-unicode-regex/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-/tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/ava/node_modules/@ava/babel-preset-stage-4/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-commonjs/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall  /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/ava/node_modules/@ava/babel-preset-stage-4/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-exponentiation-operator/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/ava/node_modules/@ava/babel-preset-stage-4/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-async-to-generator/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/postcss-import/node_modules/pkg-resolve/node_modules/jspm/node_modules/systemjs-builder/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-es2015-modules-systemjs/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/postcss-import/node_modules/pkg-resolve/node_modules/jspm/node_modules/systemjs-builder/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-global-system-wrapper/node_modules/babel-template/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/postcss-import/node_modules/pkg-resolve/node_modules/jspm/node_modules/systemjs-builder/node_modules/babel-core/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/postcss-import/node_modules/pkg-resolve/node_modules/jspm/node_modules/systemjs-builder/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-cjs-system-wrapper/node_modules/babel-template/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: > core-js@2.6.9 postinstall /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/node_modules/postcss-import/node_modules/pkg-resolve/node_modules/jspm/node_modules/systemjs-builder/node_modules/babel-plugin-transform-amd-system-wrapper/node_modules/babel-template/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
remote: > node scripts/postinstall || echo "ignore"
remote: npm ERR! Linux 4.4.0-1048-aws
remote: npm ERR! argv "/tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/.meteor/heroku_build/bin/node" "/tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/.meteor/heroku_build/bin/npm" "install"
remote: npm ERR! node v0.10.48
remote: npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
remote: npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
remote: npm ERR! bcrypt@3.0.6 install: `node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build`
remote: npm ERR! Exit status 7
remote: npm ERR! Failed at the bcrypt@3.0.6 install script 'node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build'.
remote: npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the bcrypt package,
remote: npm ERR! not with npm itself.
remote: npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
remote: npm ERR!     node-pre-gyp install --fallback-to-build
remote: npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
remote: npm ERR!     npm bugs bcrypt
remote: npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
remote: npm ERR!     npm owner ls bcrypt
remote: npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
remote: npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
remote: npm ERR!     /tmp/build_0838344e4b1148e9844c2ce1a37e95dc/npm-debug.log
remote:  !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
remote:  !     Push failed
r
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed the issue Add the $HOME environment variable after deployment, don't know why but it worked after that.